# Python second input() in a row returns empty string when

Tags: python, input, pycharm

When I'm having two input() in a row, the second one returns empty string.

```
y = input()
b = input()
print('y='+y)
print('b='+b)
```

Output:

```
2020
2020
y=2020
b=
```

However, when I'm passing `__prompt` to the second input, it works fine:

```
y = input()
b = input('inp2 ')
print('y='+y)
print('b='+b)
```

Output:

```
2020
inp2 2020
y=2020
b=2020
```

What am I missing and how can I fix it without passing `__prompt`?

Comment: Your code works as expected - apparently you're not actually running the first code example you shared, or you're not entering `2020` twice. Also, it's unclear what you mean by `__prompt` - why did you prefix it with double underscores?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It might be an issue with your runtime if you're using an IDE or something like jupyter notebooks.

Comment: I've seen several questions recently with this basic problem (second input in a row doesn't work) - looks like there's a buggy IDE out there at the moment.  At least you've found a workaround - if you really don't want a prompt, perhaps `" "` would be enough to fix the problem.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. Tried same via VSCode, worked as expected. So that was the fault of PyCharm Edu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried same using Visual Studio Code, it works as expected. So the problem is in my previous IDE (PyCharm Edu 2022.1.1)